# Wordpress Apache Adjust SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ssl, https

Hello i have a site on my own computer hosting. I setup wordpress and apache on it. Got a domain name and registered it on cloudflare. They also offer a free certificate which i got and put into folder .crt and .key files. Here is my configuration for ssl and non-ssl for apache

**HTTPS**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName hascelin.fun
    ServerAdmin hascelin@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hascelin.fun/
    ServerAlias www.hascelin.fun

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/hascelin.fun/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.hascelin.fun [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =hascelin.fun
    #RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    SSLEngine      on
    SSLCertificateFile        /home/orest/cert/hascelin.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile     /home/orest/cert/hascelin.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**HTTP**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hascelin.fun
    ServerAdmin hascelin@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hascelin.fun/
    ServerAlias www.hascelin.fun

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/hascelin.fun/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.hascelin.fun [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =hascelin.fun
    #RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    #SSLEngine      on
    #SSLCertificateFile        /home/orest/cert/hascelin.crt
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile     /home/orest/cert/hascelin.key
```

Media files are loading from http

Comment: all media files loading from http, or only few?

Comment: are you sure there is no path written in the code containing "http"? Do you have .htaccess file(s)?